# dockerfile create a image private

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to publish software commercial throught docker image

I think that is a good way to protect and distribute.

But i am not sure that how to avoid that user connect via cli to explore the image and sustract the program or database.

**what is the best way to encrypt the volume and avoid cli connection?** (via password i suppose)

i am using a dockerfile to generate te image.

by the way... best license solution?

i am using debian buster slim and openjdk base image

thanks

Comment: I am not aware of docker images being able to encrypt. However it is possible to export a tar ball of all files contained in an image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/, so with that it should not be any more or less secure than what you get without Docker....

Comment: Since you have a compiled JVM language you're better off that purely interpreted languages, but you cannot stop someone from extracting the jar file and decompiling it.  If you have a true compiled language (usually in Go, or C++, or Rust) you can build it into a `FROM scratch` image without even a shell, but the compiled binary will still be fairly accessible.